# I lost the redologs files from my test database due to a disk error

Tags: oracle, recovery

I lost the redologs files from my test database due to a disk error, when trying to open the database it presents the error below:

ORA-01589: you must use RESETLOGS or NORESETLOGS option to open bd

When executing the command

> alter database open resetlogs;

another error occurs:

ERROR on line 1:
ORA-01194: File 1 Needs More Recovery to Be Consistent
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/u02/DATA/GDQUA/datafile/system01.dbf'

Running:

> recover database;

Give the error:

ORA-00283: Recovery session canceled due to errors
ORA-01610: Recovery must be performed using the BACKUP CONTROLFILE option

Can you guys help me with this?

Comment: Did you try doing a `recover database using backup controlfile;`?

Comment: Yes a I did, but didn´t work

Answer (score 0):

Befor you open database with resetlogs,you need set "_ALLOW_RESETLOGS_CORRUPTION" parameter to ‘true’.

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET "_ALLOW_RESETLOGS_CORRUPTION"=TRUE SCOPE=SPFILE;
```